# Repeat a row of dataframe n number of times in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe

How can I repeat and bind a row of a dataframe n number of times in each dataframe of a list? So, for example with this list:

```
[[1]]
  x z y
 1 2 3

[[2]]
  x z y
 4 5 6
```

this is the desired output if n is 1:

```
[[1]]
  x z y
 1 2 3
 1 2 3
[[2]]
  x z y
 4 5 6
 4 5 6
```

Data:

```
list1 <- data.frame("x" = 1, "z" = 2, "y" = 3)
   list2 <- data.frame("x" = 4, "z" = 5, "y" = 6)
    Mylist <- list(list1, list2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply`, `do.call`, `rbind`, and `rep`. To use `rep` to create a list of replicated data frame, make sure to use the `list` function to cover your data frame.

```
lapply(Mylist, function(x){
  do.call(rbind, rep(list(x), 2))
})
# [[1]]
#   x z y
# 1 1 2 3
# 2 1 2 3
# 
# [[2]]
#   x z y
# 1 4 5 6
# 2 4 5 6
```

The other idea is to just replicate the row index as many times as you need to select the rows, but you may need to fix the row names later.

```
lapply(Mylist, function(x){
  x[rep(1, 2), ]
})
# [[1]]
#     x z y
# 1   1 2 3
# 1.1 1 2 3
# 
# [[2]]
#     x z y
# 1   4 5 6
# 1.1 4 5 6
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated the list name to remove confusion. Would you please update your answer to reflect this change?

Comment: @user1658170 Thanks for your update. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: A slight change to your second answer to generalize over data.frames with multiple rows is `lapply(Mylist, function(x) x[rep(seq_len(nrow(x)), each=2), ])`.